# DevTools - Network - Fetch/XHR. Возможно ли перехватить данные, полученные от сервера?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

После загрузки страницы JS-скрипты некоего сайта отправляют серверу запросы. Собственно нужно получить данные заголовков ответа сервера. В DevTools я могу их увидеть, но мне нужно их использовать программно.
Это как-то возможно?

Comment: Внести правки в код, который выполняет сам запрос, или _обернуть_ метод выполнения запросов своим обработчиком

Comment: Мне нравится использовать HttpAnalyzer в таких случаях